# Выборка всех объектов из БД на страницу

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, mysql

```
<?php 
$filter_city = $_POST['filter-select'];
$filter_class = $_POST['filter-class'];
include 'scripts/connect_db.php';
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM buildings WHERE city = '".$filter_city."' AND  object_class ='".$filter_class."' ORDER BY RAND()";

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

echo $row['object_name'].$row['object_class'].'<br>';

}
mysql_close();

?>
```

Есть несколько объектов у которых есть класс Бизнес, Эконом и Комфорт.
Если выбрать в `filter-class`(это `select`) класс Бизнес, то страница `result.php` выведет все объекты с классом Бизнес. Так же и с Эконом. Как сделать выборку всех объектов если в `filter-class` выбрать `все`?

```
<select name="filter-class">
  <option selected disabled>Класс</option>
  <option>Все</option>
  <option value="Бизнес">Бизнес</option>
  <option value="Комфорт">Комфорт</option>
  <option value="Эконом">Эконом</option>
</select>
```

Comment: просто делаешь запрос не `object_class  =`, а `object_class IN (...)` предварительно сделав из массива строку строк)

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, как написать в моем случае и как стоит заносить эти данные в БД(через , или ;) и какой тип должен быть

Comment: получается, мне нужно, чтобы при выборе Все на странице result выводились и Бизнес, и Комфорт, и Эконом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего надо сделать так:

В значение `Все` тоже добавить `value`, например `all`. В файле `result.php` надо подправить запрос.

```
$filter_class = $_POST['filter-class'];
$where_add = '';

if ($filter_class != 'all')
    $where_add = ' AND object_class ="'.$filter_class.'"';

include 'scripts/connect_db.php';

$strSQL = "SELECT * 
    FROM buildings 
    WHERE city = '".$filter_city."' 
    {$where_add} 
    ORDER BY RAND()";
```

В чем смысл: если прилетает значение `all`, то в качестве `$where` подставляется пустота и выбираются все марки, в ином же случае в запрос будет добавлена строка `AND object_class ='".$filter_class."`, за счет чего выберутся авто с определенной маркой.

P.S. Хочу заметить, что скорее всего БД у вас не приведена к нормальной форме, т.к. в `select` у вас хранятся значения классов авто, а должны бы численные значения. Поэтому настоятельно рекомендуется сделать нормализацию таблиц.

P.P.S. Также смею сообщить, что напрямую вставлять значения в запрос нельзя. Следует пользоваться подготовленными выражениями и расширением `mysqli/PDO` для работы с БД

Comment: спасибо :) я учту ваши замечания)